# How to compare column values of different rows with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a list of teachers, the classes they are teaching and how many students passed and how many students failed.

```
Teacher-ID       Class          Pass/Fail       Count
-------------------------------------------------------
1                English        Pass            15
1                English        Fail            5
1                Math           Pass            20
1                Math           Fail            10
2                Science        Pass            15
2                Science        Fail            10
2                Spanish        Pass            20
2                Spanish        Fail            8
```

What I want to do is get a percentage for each teacher and class combination of how many students failed.

```
Teacher-ID       Class          % Failed
-------------------------------------------------------
1                English        25%
1                Math           33%
2                Science        40%
2                Spanish        29%
```

I am stumped as to how to use SQL to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query you can use:

```
SELECT
  TeacherID,
  Class,
  SUM(CASE WHEN PassFail = 'Fail' THEN Count ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 /SUM(Count) as FailPersent
FROM tbl
GROUP BY TeacherID, Class
```

Comment: I get `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` when I try and run this. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Also, wouldn't I need to use `COUNT(*)` instead of just `COUNT`?

Comment: I don't know what you have tried, but here is a fiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb6e5e/1